# Docker IIS App getting CORS policies error

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis, containers

I created a docker image with windows server core , IIS, ASP.Net application. 
And running the container with port mapping 8000:80
But i'm getting the below error

[image]
Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Could you please post more details information about your application? It seems you used the oauth to authenticate the user?  Could you please share the details docker file?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install IIS CORS module.
you can use msiexec.exe command to install it without prompt.

Link to IIS CORS module:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Belows is the link showing how to configure it for IIS.
https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module